# Dynamic routes based on roles

Tags: symfony

I am trying to build an optional Bundle for my application. This bundle should be totally decoupled from all the other bundles. It adds some additional features / logic to existing controllers. The challenge now is, that this optional Bundle is only activated for some users.
Which means I can't use bundle inheritance to overwrite the controller, because this would overwrite it for every user.

What I wan't is some kind of User / SecurityContext aware router. That can be configured if the current user want's to go to the "home" route that this is a a different Controller action for a User with ROLE_USER_ADMIN than for the ROLE_USER.

I know that I could just check in the controller which role the current user has and then redirect, but I had some issues with that and it is not 100% decoupled.

Comment: What you want to achieve should be possible by listening to some of the `KernelEvents` like `kernel.request`. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#component-http-kernel-event-table

Comment: This is definately one option. Another one would be to write a custom router. I am not sure which one is easier. Although I was searching for a more already built in solution, if something like that exists.

Comment: Afaik the only "simple" way too keep it decoupled is by using events. But don't you think that it feels more natural to have dedicated routes for `admin_home` and `user_home` of simply extending the default view if a user has `ROLE_USER_ADMIN`?

Comment: Sorry I just used an bad example. I actually have a role for beta users that get more features. And they have different home screens. And I don't want an IF condition on the userrole, everywhere, where I link to home.

Comment: You don't need conditions everywhere for the link generation, but you could use conditions on the homescreen (= in the view of the homescreen).

Comment: I wanted to make the whole bundle optional. So I try to add all this things ONLY in the additional bundle without changing the original bundle. I could only achieve that with bundle inheritance and conditions in the views then.

Comment: exactly. When using bundle inheritance you could even simply override the corresponding controller action and model your necessry logic there and e.g. use another template or forward to another option, etc.